# How can I use my "render" function in a different class in three.js?

Tags: javascript, function, class, three.js

I'm new to three.js and I am making a bowling game.
But I have an issue here, I made the physics in a class and now I need to access a function from my "Application" class.
I really don't get the issue here and I'm pretty lost.

Application Class:

```
export class Application {
    constructor() {  
        this.objects = [];
        this.createScene();
    }

    createScene() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        this.render();

    }

    getMesh(){
        return this.curveObject;
    }
    update(){
        
    }

    render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {    
        this.render();
    });
        this.objects.forEach((object) => {
        object.update();
    });
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
}
```

Animate Function inside "Physics" class:

```
  animate(){
       if (this.pinTest){
      //  console.log(this.pinTest);
        this.pin1Mesh.position.copy(this.pin1Body.position);
        this.pin1Mesh.quaternion.copy(this.pin1Body.quaternion);
        this.pinTest.position.copy(this.pin1Body.position);
        this.pinTest.quaternion.copy(this.pin1Body.quaternion);
    }
    // I need to call render here
    //this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}
```

Comment: You could have a base class that contains your animate function. Then inherit from that.

Comment: Something like a main class?

Comment: Well, the implementation would depend on how many animations you have and their dependencies. Do you have multiple animations that have different needs?

Comment: No, not actually

Comment: OK, so if you have basic needs, you can just have a base class that contains your animation and inherit from it. Or, you could have an animation class that you pass your relevant object to. The relevant object would need to supply the animation it's variables.

Comment: Great. Let me know how you got on.

Comment: Could you please show me an example?

Comment: OK. I've added two examples using the ideas I mentioned above. Neither one is better/worse than the other. It all depends on what you plan to do in your fuller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Base class example:**

```js
class baseAnimation {
  animate() {
    if (this.pinTest) {
      //  console.log(this.pinTest);
      this.pin1Mesh.position.copy(this.pin1Body.position);
      this.pin1Mesh.quaternion.copy(this.pin1Body.quaternion);
      this.pinTest.position.copy(this.pin1Body.position);
      this.pinTest.quaternion.copy(this.pin1Body.quaternion);
    } else
      console.log("pinTest === false");
  }
}

class Physics extends baseAnimation {

}



let test = new Physics();

test.pinTest = false;

test.animate();
```

**Passing an object to an `Animation` class (using static method) example:**

```js
class Animation {
  static animate(obj) {
    if (obj.pinTest) {
      //  console.log(this.pinTest);
      obj.pin1Mesh.position.copy(obj.pin1Body.position);
      obj.pin1Mesh.quaternion.copy(obj.pin1Body.quaternion);
      obj.pinTest.position.copy(obj.pin1Body.position);
      obj.pinTest.quaternion.copy(obj.pin1Body.quaternion);
    } else
      console.log("pinTest === false");
  }
}

class Physics {

}

let test = new Physics();

test.pinTest = false;

Animation.animate(test);
```

Comment: If it helps please accept and vote accordingly. Thanks